# How to bind to the control property itself, instead of DataContext value property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a user control. With XAML. It has it's own properties, it has its `ViewModel` object set as DataContext:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="0">
  <ComboBox.DataContext>
    <vm:WindowsProfilePicker />
  </ComboBox.DataContext>
```

Binding to its DataContext value properties is super easy and works as expected.

Let's say:

```
<Image Source="{Binding UserImage}" />
```

`UserImage` is a property of the `ViewModel`.

The `Image` element is however a part of my user control. The control has its own property named `ImageSize` defined as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSizeProperty
  = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ImageSize",
    typeof(double),
    typeof(WindowsProfilePicker),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(126.0)
);
```

Of course we have getter and setter for it in code:

```
public double ImageSize {
  get => (double)GetValue(ImageSizeProperty);
  set => SetValue(ImageSizeProperty, value);
}
```

Now I would want to reference that property in my `UserControl`'s XAML. It looks like this:

```
<Image
  Width="
    {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:WindowsProfilePicker},
      Path=ImageSize}"
  Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:WindowsProfilePicker},
      Path=ImageSize}"
  Source="{Binding UserImage}" />
```

Nice? Not really, and it doesn't work. I get no errors, no warnings, but the image size is not set. The image in the control sets its size from the source bitmap size. When I replace my binding with a number, it works, the size is fixed. However, I want `ImageSize` property of my new control to be used as `Image` `Width` and `Height`. What am I doing wrong?

BTW, obviously I don't want the property to be bound with my ViewModel, because it's strictly presentation feature, unrelated to data.

The visuals like sizes must be set in XAML (optimally as styles), the data (in my case user profile pictures) in code, the control's ViewModel.

Comment: It is generally wrong that a UserControl has its own view model, i.e. sets its own DataContext. It would instead expose dependency properties that are bound to the properties of an object in its inherited DataContext, i.e. the one supplied by its parent element, e.g. a Window or Page.

Comment: In the UserControl's XAML you use RelativeSource Bindings, like `<Image Source="{Binding UserImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />`, where UserImage is a dependency property of the control.

Comment: Have you checked the `Output` window? Maybe there are binding or conversion errors?

Comment: @Clemens: So is it a good practice to populate the item container in code-behind instead of ViewModel? I mean the main module "consuming" the control would use only the selection value (current item). The control is a user profile picker, so it's independent from the application, results depend only on user's system.

Comment: @IDarkCoder: I checked. No errors or other messages indicating invalid binding.

Comment: @Harry Not sure which item container and current item you are referring to. Your question is about a UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try configuring property metadata somewhat like this:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSizeProperty
      = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ImageSize",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(WindowsProfilePicker),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((double)126.0, 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault
            | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender
            | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure)
    );

    [TypeConverter(typeof(LengthConverter))]
    public double ImageSize
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ImageSizeProperty);
        set => SetValue(ImageSizeProperty, value);
    }
```

or

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSizeProperty
      = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ImageSize",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(WindowsProfilePicker),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((double)126.0, 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault
            | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender
            | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure)
    {
         BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
         DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
     });
```

(`AffectsRender` & `AffectsMeasure` may not be necessary though)

Comment: Well, weridly - nothing happens in designer view even after rebuilding the whole thing, however it works at runtime! I guess like additional options helped with propagation of the size value, I wonder why it doesn't work at design time. The designer manages to gather the data from system and build all the images, but it fails to pass a double value from one XAML element to another.

Comment: @Harry I agree it's very annoying that it doesn't work in designer reliably. Although, if you add your UserControl to another control or window and then rebuild, it should work. Though this behavior is unpredictable at times (for example sometimes I need to close the xaml file and open it again for it to work; it also tends to behave differently if your UC is in the same project vs in a separate one).

Comment: @Harry you may also want to experiment with other FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions?view=netframework-4.8 Maybe something such as "AffectsParentMeasure" will do the trick?

Comment: It's possible, because the inner Image element is the only reference point for sizing the outer elements.